# azure data factory - detect trigger changes in log analytics

Tags: azure, logging, triggers, azure-data-factory, kql

Would like to know a KQL query to detect changes in ADF triggers.

Looking at Log Analytics since we are sending all logs to LA, I see several tables are created and populated, some are not.

AzureActivity looked promising but I only see Start/Success under ActivityStatusValue for the specific trigger name.

AzureDiagnostics does not appear to contain any data.
AzureMetrics has quite a few Metrics under MetricName but nothing close to what I'm looking for.

Thanks for any help you may provide.

Comment: AzureActivity
| where Category == "DataFactoryPipelineRun"
| where OperationName == "Microsoft.DataFactory/factories/pipelines/create"
| where ResourceProvider == "MICROSOFT.DATAFACTORY"
| where ActivityStatusValue == "Succeeded"
| where Details contains "New-AzDataFactoryPipeline"

Comment: Thanks. Looks like this query will give you information when a new pipeline is created successfully. BTW, the last field, "Details" does not exist on my Log Analitycs AzureActivity table.

Comment: What I'm looking for is to detect when a trigger was changed and by whom.

Comment: To detect the change through tirgger you can use the 'Azure Diagnostic' table ,   following query may help AzureDiagnostics
| where ResourceProvider == "MICROSOFT.DATAFACTORY"
| where Category == "PipelineRun"
| where OperationName == "Microsoft.DataFactory/factories/pipelineruns/write"
| where TriggerName_s != PrevTriggerName_s or TriggerStatus_s != PrevTriggerStatus_s
| project TimeGenerated, TriggerName_s, PrevTriggerName_s, TriggerStatus_s, PrevTriggerStatus_s

Answer (score 1):

REST API Solution (Using ADF and SQL Server):

Web Activity JSON:

```
{
"name": "Initial ADF Triggers Logs",
"type": "WebActivity",
"dependsOn": [],
"policy": {
    "timeout": "7.00:00:00",
    "retry": 1,
    "retryIntervalInSeconds": 180,
    "secureOutput": false,
    "secureInput": false
},
"userProperties": [],
"typeProperties": {
    "url": {
        "value": "https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/@{pipeline().parameters.SubscriptionId}/resourceGroups/@{pipeline().parameters.ResourceGroupName}/providers/Microsoft.DataFactory/factories/@{pipeline().parameters.DataFactoryName}/triggers?api-version=2018-06-01",
        "type": "Expression"
    },
    "method": "GET",
    "body": {
        "value": "{\n\"lastUpdatedAfter\": \"@{pipeline().parameters.MaxLastUpdateTime}\",\n\"lastUpdatedBefore\": \"@{utcnow()}\",\n\"filters\": []\n}",
        "type": "Expression"
    },
    "authentication": {
        "type": "MSI",
        "resource": {
            "value": "https://management.azure.com/",
            "type": "Expression"
        }
    }
}
}
```

The output of that looks like this:

[image: API Output]

You could then read that into a stored procedure and write to a backend table and do whatever spanning and historical tracking you would like. Here is the Stored Procedure and Table DDL to make it happen:

Procedure:

```
ALTER Procedure [AzureDataFactory].[PopulateTriggerLog_tmp] (
@json NVARCHAR(MAX),
@DataFactoryName VARCHAR(50) = NULL
)
as
BEGIN TRY 
select @json j
;
insert into AzureDataFactory.TriggerLog_tmp (
TriggerId
,TriggerName
,TriggerType
,frequency
,interval
,startTime
,endTime
,timeZone
,ScheduleMinutes
,ScheduleHours
,ScheduleWeekdays
,ScheduleMonthDays
,MonthlyOccuranceDay
,MonthlyOccurance
,FirstPipelineName
,Descriptions
,RunTimeState
,etag
,DataFactoryName
,ETLUpdateTimestamp
)
SELECT
    JSON_VALUE ( j.[value], '$.id' ) AS TriggerId,
    JSON_VALUE ( j.[value], '$.name' ) AS TriggerName,
    JSON_VALUE ( j.[value], '$.properties.type' ) AS TriggerType,
    JSON_VALUE ( j.[value], '$.properties.typeProperties.recurrence.frequency' ) AS Frequency,
    JSON_VALUE ( j.[value], '$.properties.typeProperties.recurrence.interval' ) AS Interval,
    JSON_VALUE ( j.[value], '$.properties.typeProperties.recurrence.startTime' ) AS StartTime,
    JSON_VALUE ( j.[value], '$.properties.typeProperties.recurrence.endTime' ) AS EndTime,
    JSON_VALUE ( j.[value], '$.properties.typeProperties.recurrence.timeZone' ) AS TimeZone,
    REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(JSON_QUERY ( j.[value], '$.properties.typeProperties.recurrence.schedule.minutes'), ' ', ''), '[', ''), ']', '') AS ScheduleMinutes,
    REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(JSON_QUERY ( j.[value], '$.properties.typeProperties.recurrence.schedule.hours'), ' ', ''), '[', ''), ']', '') AS ScheduleHours,
    REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(JSON_QUERY ( j.[value], '$.properties.typeProperties.recurrence.schedule.weekDays'), ' ', ''), '[', ''), ']', '') AS ScheduleWeekdays,
    REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(JSON_QUERY ( j.[value], '$.properties.typeProperties.recurrence.schedule.monthDays'), ' ', ''), '[', ''), ']', '') AS ScheduleMonthDays, --Added V2 ijt 12/6/22
    JSON_VALUE ( (JSON_QUERY ( j.[value], '$.properties.typeProperties.recurrence.schedule.monthlyOccurrences[0]')), '$.day') AS MonthlyOccuranceDay, --Added V2 ijt 12/6/22
    JSON_VALUE ( (JSON_QUERY ( j.[value], '$.properties.typeProperties.recurrence.schedule.monthlyOccurrences[0]')), '$.occurrence') AS MonthlyOccurance, --Added V2 ijt 12/6/22
    JSON_VALUE ( (JSON_QUERY ( j.[value], '$.properties.pipelines[0]')), '$.pipelineReference.referenceName') AS FirstPipelineName,
    JSON_VALUE ( j.[value], '$.properties.description' ) AS descriptions,
    JSON_VALUE ( j.[value], '$.properties.runtimeState' ) AS runtimeState,
    JSON_VALUE ( j.[value], '$.etag' ) AS etag,
    @DataFactoryName AS DataFactoryName,
    getdate() as ETLUpdateTimestamp
FROM OPENJSON( @json ) j
;
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
 IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0
    ROLLBACK;
    THROW;
END CATCH
```

Table DDL:

```
CREATE TABLE [AzureDataFactory].[TriggerLog_tmp](
[TriggerId] [varchar](250) NOT NULL,
[TriggerName] [varchar](100) NULL,
[TriggerType] [varchar](25) NULL,
[frequency] [varchar](10) NULL,
[interval] [int] NULL,
[startTime] [datetime] NULL,
[endTime] [datetime] NULL,
[timeZone] [varchar](50) NULL,
[ScheduleMinutes] [varchar](500) NULL,
[ScheduleHours] [varchar](500) NULL,
[ScheduleWeekdays] [varchar](500) NULL,
[ScheduleMonthDays] [varchar](50) NULL,
[MonthlyOccuranceDay] [varchar](500) NULL,
[MonthlyOccurance] [int] NULL,
[Descriptions] [varchar](800) NULL,
[RunTimeState] [varchar](500) NULL,
[FirstPipelineName] [varchar](50) NULL,
[etag] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
[DataFactoryName] [varchar](50) NULL,
[ETLUpdateTimestamp] [datetime] NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

This I know is not through Log Analytics, but I know from experience it is a highly effective way of tracking triggers across ALL Azure Data Factories, which is imperative once you have dozens of ADF's to support. It's always fun when your director asks you, is there anything running in ADF right now...

Comment: Thank, can't wait to try this approach.

Answer (score 0):

The easy way to do this is to look at the Activity Log right under the Overview menu option for the resource. You can select a time period and you can filter by Operation Name, in my case I searched for Trigger Stop and that gave me the information I needed after downloading the file to a CSV worksheet.